# How to run Selected Text using activate.bat instead of ps1 in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

Running into this weird issue and I don't seem to be able to find a solution online or forums. My VS Code was working fine last night, but this morning when I launched VS Code and trying to execute code (in Python) using the Run Selected Text feature, I kept getting "& "C:/Users/jiejenn/Documents/Python Venv/vtest2/Scripts/activate.ps1"
& was unexpected at this time." error message.

In the past, VS Code is using the activate.bat file, which is what I want, but all of sudden, PowerShell took over the command. I am trying to revert back to using the activate.bat file instead of activate.ps1.

Can anyone provide me with some guidance how can it be done? Thanks.

I have already Googled for the past 2 hours, haven't find any solution that solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your default terminal application changed from `cmd` to `PowerShell`, possibly during an update. Click the terminal dropdown button and then Select Default Profile to change it back to `cmd`.

See also [this related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67785467/1666676).