# VS Code trying to run .../Activat.ps1 in cmd terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, cmd, virtualenv

I'm using VS Code for a Python project using a virtualenv. I switched my deafult terminal from **powershell** to **cmd** as VS Code was not happy executing powershell scripts.

Now when I open a terminal in my project it opens cmd (as desired), but automatically tries tor run `.../Scripts/Activate.ps1`, which it doesn't like. I want it to run `.../Scripts/Activate.bat` as we are in cmd. Runnning it manually for now, but would be nice if I didn't have to.

No doubt there is a setting somewhere to change this, but I cannot find it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem related to the Python extension, it should be fixed in the last update.

You can get some information from [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/16175).